# Qt: Organize Project Into Nested Subdirectories

Tags: c++, qt

I am used to organizing my C++ projects as so:

```
project
↪include
  ↪foo
    ↪bar
      ↪A.h
      ↪B.h
↪src
 ↪foo
  ↪bar
    ↪A.cpp
    ↪B.cpp
```

I add the "include" folder into my include path so then I can do things like this:

```
#include <foo/bar/A.h>
```

My question is, how do I get this same structure to "play nicely" with Qt and Qt Creator?

I have read that .pri files in each subdirectory are one approach, but, when I attempted this, I ended up with the following:
[image]

Is there any way to get Qt to manage the files just as showed in my first example?

**EDIT**

I may have come up with a solution that works, though I don't know if it is correct.  It produces the following in Qt Creator:

[image]

Here is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

include("$$PWD/include/include.pri")
include("$$PWD/src/src.pri")

INCLUDEPATH += "$$PWD/include"

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

And include/foo/foo.pri:

```
include("$$PWD/bar/bar.pri")
```

And include/foo/bar/bar.pri:

```
HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/A.h \
    $$PWD/B.h
```

If you Add a new or existing file to one of these folders using Qt Creator, it automatically updates the pri file.

Comment: Can you please post your project files along with dummy source/header files?

Comment: @aalimian See my edit for some code snippets and what it looks like in Qt Creator.  My question is, is what I did the correct/best way to do this?